# Setting default to NULL with format() returns unexpected string

Tags: python, python-requests

In my API call defined below to retrieve the last 24 hrs of data, the normal request url would be:

```
https://api.foobar.com/data
```

That is why I have set the `next_page` parameter default to NULL.

However, sometimes the API will return a unique URL at the end of the json (such as https://api.foobar.com/data?page%237hfaj39), which indicates another page exists and another `get_data` request needs to be made to retrieve the remainder.

In that case, the `{next_page}` parameter will be set to whatever this unique url returned would be.

My problem is after adding the `{next_page}` parameter, the default `get_data` url somehow gets 4 unwanted characters - `%7B%7D` appended so that the request looks like

https://api.foobar.com/data%7B%7D and of course the API does not respond.

In UTF-8 encoding %7B%7D are two brackets `{}`

Why does this happen and what am I doing wrong here in terms of formatting?  Using `None` in place of `{}` also does not work.

The code:

```
def make_request(url, params={}, headers={}):
    r = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
    print r.url
    if(not r.status_code is 200):
        print "Error access API" + r.text
        exit()
    return r.json()

def get_data(access_token, next_page={}):
    end_time = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
    start_time = end_time - (seconds_in_day * 1000)
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token, 'start_time': str(start_time), 'end_time': str(end_time)}
    url = 'https://api.foobar.com/data{next_page}'.format(next_page=next_page)
    return make_request(url, headers=headers)
```

Note: the API call works when the `next_page` parameter is removed

Comment: What is `make_request`, and does it accept query parameters in the form `params=dict`?

Comment: I have included that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `next_page={}`, you will get unexpected formatting results. If you try the following:

```
>>> '{}'.format({})
'{}'
```

As you can see, instead of the desired `''`, you get a string with two brackets. This is because:

```
>>> str({})
'{}'
```

A similar thing happens with `None`:

```
>>> '{}'.format(None)
'None'
>>> str(None)
'None'
```

To fix this, instead of `next_page={}`, try `next_page=''`, because `.format()` will do this:

```
>>> '{}'.format('')
''
```